# why are these two successive reads executed in the same transaction?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, transactions

I have a separate thread inserting rows in a table, committing after each row. Then, on my main thread I do two successive reads on that table (`SELECT COUNT(*)`) with a sleep period of 1000 ms between the two reads.

The two reads observe the same number of rows even though the reads should (?) happen in different transactions. The only way to get the two reads to return different values is to add a `commit` between the two reads (call the method with `breakTransaction` set to `true`). Otherwise they appear to be executed in the same transaction.

The `ds` used in the code below is of type `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource`:

```
 public void readTwoCounts(boolean breakTransaction) throws SQLException {
     Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
     conn.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE);
     PreparedStatement ps1 = null;
     ResultSet         rs1 = null;
     PreparedStatement ps2 = null;
     ResultSet         rs2 = null;
     try {
         Integer count1 = null;
         Integer count2 = null;
         {  // 1st READ
            ps1 = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a");
            rs1 = ps1.executeQuery();
            rs1.next();
            count1 = rs1.getInt("count");
         }
         if (breakTransaction)
            conn.commit();
         try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
         {  // 2nd READ
            ps2 = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a");
            rs2 = ps2.executeQuery();
            rs2.next();
            count2 = rs2.getInt("count");
         }
        System.out.printf("%d %d\n", count1, count2);
    } finally {
        DbUtils.closeQuietly(conn, ps1, rs1);
        DbUtils.closeQuietly(conn, ps2, rs2);
    }
}
```

My question is:

When do successive reads on a `Connection` object happen on the same transaction and why do I have to explicitly call `commit` to ensure they happen in different transactions?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Well, that's how transactions work: while you've not committed or rollbacked, you stay in the same transaction. Otherwise, every DB operation would define its own transaction, which is what autocommit does, and what you typically don't want in a serious app, since you want multiple operations to be atomic, consistent, and isolated from the other ones.

Comment: @JBNizet OK, so so long as I have `autocommit` set to false, I don't need to explicitly `commit` anything on the `Connection` object and all reads on the same `Connection` object will be on the same transaction. Right?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name PostgreSQL

Comment: Right. You're always inside a transaction, and calling commit() commits it.